# PHP - Get non-empty values from 2 arrays to 1 array

Tags: php, arrays

Here's the situation:
I have 2 arrays like so:

```
<?php
$array1 = [
    'key1' => 437776,
    'key2' => 'Bar',
    'key3' => ''
];
$array2 = [
    'key1' => '',
    'key2' => 'Bar',
    'key3' => 'Foo'
];
```

What I actually want is a `magic_function` that takes as params `$array1` and `$array2`, and returns an array that does not contains any empty value (the values should be obtained from `$array1` and `$array2`). In this case it will be:

```
$array_returned = [
    'key1' => 437776,
    'key2' => 'Bar',
    'key3' => 'Foo'
];
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Merge the array, get the unique values and then filter the array.

Comment: @Rizier123, Ow that works, Thanks :D

Comment: Don't forget to put it in a function and call it magic.

Comment: @Rizier123 Heh xD, right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, It could be done by using `array_filter`:

```
$array1 = array_filter([
    'key1' => 437776,
    'key2' => 'Bar',
    'key3' => ''
]);
$array2 = array_filter([
    'key1' => '',
    'key2' => 'Bar',
    'key3' => 'Foo'
]);
$array_returned = array_merge($array1, $array2);
```